# Nullability Mismatch Between Property Getter and Setter?

Tags: c#, .net-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I've written a class that implements IDataParameter in C# with .NET 8.
I get CS8767 on the Setter for this code:

```
public class TestDataParameter: IDataParameter
{
   ...

   public string ParameterName
   {
      get; set;
   } = "";
   ...
}
```

Making the return type string? leads to CS8766 on the Getter.

```
public class TestDataParameter: IDataParameter
{
   ...

   public string? ParameterName
   {
      get; set;
   } = "";
   ...
}
```

This is extremely annoying. The interface declares the property as string. I don't understand why it would need different nullabilities for the getter and the setter and how this should be implemented.
IDataParameter declares `string ParameterName { get; set; }` so implementing the property non-nullable should be right.
Does anyone have any idea why this happens and how to deal with it correctly?
Thanks, Alex.

Comment: Is the interface definition also in `#nullable enable` context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the warning you can follow the approach which [the interfaces uses itself](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/83b0d939bedadf7d782b0b26307c2d8c1d5b76f4/src/libraries/System.Data.Common/src/System/Data/IDataParameter.cs#L8) - use the `AllowNullAttribute`:

```cs
public class TestDataParameter : IDataParameter
{
    // ...
    [AllowNull]
    public string ParameterName { get; set; } = "";
    // ...
}
```

You might want though to switch from the auto-property implementation to one which will maintain the contract (i.e. you can pass null but null is never returned as for example [`OdbcParameter`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/83b0d939bedadf7d782b0b26307c2d8c1d5b76f4/src/libraries/System.Data.Odbc/src/System/Data/Odbc/OdbcParameter.cs#L224) does):

```cs
private string? _parameterName = "";

[AllowNull]
public string ParameterName
{
    get => _parameterName ?? string.Empty;
    set => _parameterName = value;
}
```

See also:

- [Attributes for null-state static analysis interpreted by the C# compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis)